# Getting Error: Array expected for`personalizations` in Next js app with Sendgrid API

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I have a file in my api folder called sendAlerts.js
I keep getting the Error: Array expected for`personalizations` in http://localhost:3000/api/sendAlerts

This is my code that's in api/sendAlerts:

```
const mail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

mail.setApiKey(process.env.SENGRID_APIKEY);

export default async (req, res) => {
  await mail.send({
    personalizations: `${req.body.personalizations}`,
    from: 'david.gregory.medero@gmail.com',
    subject: `${req.body.subject}`,
    text: `${req.body.message}`
  });
  res.status(200).json({ status: 'Ok' });
}
```

Here is the function that submits the message to that API endpoint:

```
  async function handleOnSubmit() {
    await fetch('/api/sendAlerts', {
      body: JSON.stringify({
        personalizations: [personalizationState],
        subject: `${product.title} in size ${variantTitle} is now available!`,
        message: `${product.title} in size ${variantTitle} is now available!`,
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      method: 'POST',
    })
  }
```

And my personalizationState looks like this in the console:

0: {to: Array(1), bcc: Array(2)}

0:
bcc: Array(2)
0: {email: 'dmederoudemy@gmail.com'}
1: {email: 'dmedero@getwrecked.com'}

to: Array(1)
0: {email: 'david.gregory.medero@gmail.com'}

I have no idea why I'm getting that error. My personalizationState is inside an Array. Am I missing something???

Edit: I refactored the submit function for clarity:

```
      async function handleOnSubmit() {
        await fetch('/api/sendAlerts', {
          body: JSON.stringify({
            personalizations: [
                {
                "to": [
                {
                  "email": "david.gregory.medero@gmail.com"
                }
                ],
                "bcc": [
                {
                    "email": "dmederoudemy@gmail.com"
                }, 
                {
                    "email": "dmedero@getwrecked.com"
                }
                ]
            }
            ],
            subject: `${product.title} in size ${variantTitle} is now available!`,
            message: `${product.title} in size ${variantTitle} is now available!`,
          }),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          method: 'POST',
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your api/sendAlerts file you are setting the `personalization` property in the send function as a string. You need to remove the template literal where you get the personalization from req. See here:

```
const mail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

mail.setApiKey(process.env.SENGRID_APIKEY);

export default async (req, res) => {
  await mail.send({
    personalizations: req.body.personalizations, // no need for template literal assuming the personalizationState is an array
    from: 'david.gregory.medero@gmail.com',
    subject: `${req.body.subject}`,
    text: `${req.body.message}`
  });
  res.status(200).json({ status: 'Ok' });
}
```

Also, judging from the log of your `personalizationState` you also do not need to wrap it in array since it is already an array. so in the function that submits the message to that API endpoint you should change it to this:

```
 personalizations: personalizationState, // personalizationState looks already like an array, no need for []
```

---

UPDATE: Please see the code below, I created a Test component which renders a button that sends to the API endpoint. Also, removed the template literal from api/sendAlerts. Here is api/sendAlerts:

```
const mail = require("@sendgrid/mail");

mail.setApiKey(process.env.SENGRID_APIKEY);

export default async (req, res) => {
    await mail.send({
        personalizations: req.body.personalizations,
        from: "<YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS>@gmail.com",
        subject: `${req.body.subject}`,
        text: `${req.body.message}`,
    });
    res.status(200).json({ status: "Ok" });
};
```

Here is the Test component, just import it anywhere and run a test to check:

```
const TestButton = () => {
    async function handleOnSubmit() {
        await fetch("/api/sendAlerts", {
            body: JSON.stringify({
                personalizations: [
                    {
                        to: [
                            {
                                email: "<<YOUREMAIL@gmail>>.com",
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
                subject: "Test Message",
                message: "Here is a test message",
            }),
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            method: "POST",
        });
    }

    return <button onClick={handleOnSubmit}>Send Email</button>;
};

export default TestButton;
```

Comment: Hi score30! Thanks for the quick reply. If I remove the template literal I get Error: Provide at least one of to, cc or bcc. I also refactored the submit function for clarity but it doesn't fix anything, still get the same errors.

Comment: Thank you for the update, I just finished creating a test environment, and was able to successfully send an email. Your updated personalization array looks good and you should be able to remove the template literal in api/sendAlert and send. I will update my code now.

Comment: Please take a look now

Comment: Ok I think I now know what the real problem is. I removed everything having to do with personalization and just added to: "david.gregory.medero@gmail.com" and I get Error: Unauthorized. I should authorize a different email address or use a domain instead. I'm aware that single senders from gmail aren't recommended by SendGrid.

Comment: Gotcha, I setup sendgrid with a single sender as well, in the api/sendAlerts I made sure to use the same email address that I used in sendgrid (the one I verified) as the `from` property. The email went into spam folder but it worked for sure.

Comment: Ok I finally managed to send emails. It worked after I put the API key directly in the api/sendAlerts.js file. For some reason, it doesn't work when I try to import it from my env.local file as process.env.SENGRID_APIKEY. Thanks for all your help score30!

Comment: Glad you could fix it, no problem!